# Put Cursor In found result from sublime text search

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I would like to put cursor all my found search result because I would like to insert text manual for selected text result. Eg

```
array(
        'id'          => 'g_arch_layout',
        'label'       => 'Select Layout For Gallery Archive Page',
        'desc'        => 'You could select your custom layout for gallery archive page!',
        'std'         => '',
        'type'        => 'select',
        'section'     => 'gallery_settings',
        'rows'        => '',
        'post_type'   => '',
        'taxonomy'    => '',
        'min_max_step'=> '',
        'class'       => '',
        'condition'   => '',
        'operator'    => '',
        'choices'     => array( 
          array(
            'value'       => '2col_layout',
            'label'       => '2Column Layout',
            'src'         => ''
          ),
          array(
            'value'       => 'filter_layout',
            'label'       => 'Filter Layout',
            'src'         => ''
          )
        )
      ),
      array(
        'id'          => 'sb_layout',
        'label'       => 'Sidebar Layout For all',
        'desc'        => 'This will effect for all of the pages, post, custom post type and all other pages',
        'std'         => '',
        'type'        => 'select',
        'section'     => 'sidebar_settings',
        'rows'        => '',
        'post_type'   => '',
        'taxonomy'    => '',
        'min_max_step'=> '',
        'class'       => '',
        'condition'   => '',
        'operator'    => '',
        'choices'     => array( 
          array(
            'value'       => 'right_sb',
            'label'       => 'Right Sidebar Single',
            'src'         => ''
          ),
          array(
            'value'       => 'no_sb',
            'label'       => 'Fullwidth Single',
            'src'         => ''
          ),
          array(
            'value'       => 'left_sb',
            'label'       => 'Left Sidebar Single',
            'src'         => ''
          )
        )
      ),
      array(
        'id'          => 'sb_page_layout',
        'label'       => 'Sidebar Layout For Pages',
        'desc'        => 'You could customize sidebar Layout for All Pages on the site! It will effect all the pages',
        'std'         => '',
        'type'        => 'select',
        'section'     => 'sidebar_settings',
        'rows'        => '',
        'post_type'   => '',
        'taxonomy'    => '',
        'min_max_step'=> '',
        'class'       => '',
        'condition'   => '',
        'operator'    => '',
        'choices'     => array( 
          array(
            'value'       => 'right_sb',
            'label'       => 'Right Sidebar Page',
            'src'         => ''
          ),
          array(
            'value'       => 'no_sb',
            'label'       => 'Fullwidth Page',
            'src'         => ''
          ),
          array(
            'value'       => 'left_sb',
            'label'       => 'Left Sidebar Page',
            'src'         => ''
          )
        )
      ),
```

For example, I wanna search and select 'desc'  => ' all from this kind of multi array. So my question is , Is that possbile to **find and selector** or to **find and put cursor**?  As you know, sublime has muti code line type at the same time ,one of those is work, we can be able to edit. My sublime text is version 2

Comment: Have you read the [Sublime multi-select docs](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/multiple_selection_with_the_keyboard.html)?

Comment: @jcm Thanks! I got it now